# Keyboard shortcut to merge cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to merge cells in Google Sheets? I've looked and can't find it.
F4 doesn't repeat merging cells either. I'm on OSX, Apple keyboard.

Anyone been able to do this with a shortcut? I have to merge an ungodly amount of cells and would prefer to not have to use the drop down menus to do it.

Comment: There was a saving grace workaround in my case - maybe it will apply to your case as well. When pasting unmerged my cells, I just re-merged them in batch, but selecting all the affected rows and using "Merge Horizontally" - this merges all selected cells in each selected row, without merging any cells together across rows.

Answer (score 22):

There doesn't seem to be a native shortcut, but you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select "Merge All" quickly from the dropdown menu.

Comment: What's the equivalent of this on a mac?

Comment: See @Yu De Lim's answer below: use "control option" (menu keyboard shortcut letters) in this case:
control-option-"o"-"m" (enter)

Answer (score 13):

Use @Pikachu's solution (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd>) for the first one then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> (Edit - Redo) for the rest. This assumes you're doing them one after the other, as I am.

Answer (score 8):

Use @Pikachu's solution (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd>). On a mac the equivalent is <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I've been looking for the "control option" command to open menus in drive for soooo long! Thank you.

Comment: +1 for mac equivalent.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the following works: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, easiest way: 
1. copy a merged cell. 
2. paste it on top of a the cell/row you want to merge.

fastest method.

Answer (score 1):

I created a macro, you just need to set it to run when shift, ctrl, alt & "number" is pressed.

Macro script:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function Unavngivetmakro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().mergeAcross();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS this works like a charm:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that merging the first set of cells manually, then selecting ALL the cells you want merged the same way, then using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> works as well and saves a ton of time.